# Prime number check doesn't work as it should

Tags: c++, for-loop, if-statement, nested-loops, primes

I'll try to keep this short. So my task is to find the last prime number in an array, if there's any. But right now my program assigns any number it wants from the array to the lastPrimeNumber variable. Any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int numbers[10] = {0};
    int numbersCount = 10;
    bool areEven = true;

    cout << "Numbers: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < numbersCount; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = rand() % 10 + 1;
        cout << numbers[i] << " ";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numbersCount; i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] % 2 != 0)
        {
            cout << "\nNot all numbers are even" << endl;
            areEven = false;
            break;
        }
        if (areEven)
        {
            cout << "\nAll numbers are even" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    // Looking for the last prime number in an array

    int lastPrimeNumber = 0;
    bool isPrime = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbersCount; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 2; j < numbers[i]/2; j++)
        {
            if (numbers[i] % j == 0 || numbers[i] < 2)
            {
                isPrime = false;
            }
        }
        if(isPrime)
        {
            lastPrimeNumber = numbers[i];
        }
    }

    cout << endl << lastPrimeNumber;
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run this code, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for and if you don't know how to use it, this is a good opportunity to learn running your program one line at a time in a debugger, monitoring all variables and their values as they change and analysing your program's logic and execution. It should be possible for you to use your debugger to find all simple problems in this and all future programs you write, all by yourself.

Comment: I did found that, while outputting the lastPrimeNumber variable inside the prime number check loop. And for some reason even not prime numbers are assigned to the lastPrimeNumber variable, but I can't find the reason why.

Comment: Make a function `bool isPrime(int x)` and test that. And then you might want to search the array from the end till you hit a prime or the front.

Comment: Your debugger will tell you why, since it shows you exactly what happens after each statement gets executed, one by one. Most debugger will even let you set a watch, where the program will run until some variable changes, then it stops on the line that changes it, and you see exactly why the variable was changed, and where. Knowing how to effectively use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters this for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbersCount; i++)
{
    if (numbers[i] % 2 != 0)
    {
        cout << "\nNot all numbers are even" << endl;
        areEven = false;
        break;
    }
    if (areEven)
    {
        cout << "\nAll numbers are even" << endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

contains a logical error. If the first element of the array is an even value then the program outputs

```
cout << "\nAll numbers are even" << endl;
```

that in general is wrong.

Instead you should write for example

```
for (int i = 0; areEven && i < numbersCount; i++)
{
    areEven = numbers[i] % 2 == 0;
}

if ( areEven )
{
    cout << "\nAll numbers are even" << endl;
}
else
{
      cout << "\nNot all numbers are even" << endl;
}
```

Within these for loops

```
int lastPrimeNumber = 0;
bool isPrime = true;
for (int i = 0; i < numbersCount; i++)
{
    for (int j = 2; j < numbers[i]/2; j++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] % j == 0 || numbers[i] < 2)
        {
            isPrime = false;
        }
    }
    if(isPrime)
    {
        lastPrimeNumber = numbers[i];
    }
}
```

you do not reset the variable `isPrime` before the inner for loop.

And the condition in the for loop is incorrect

```
    for (int j = 2; j < numbers[i]/2; j++)
```

Due to the condition the number `4` can be considered as a prime number.

And moreover this condition

```
numbers[i] < 2
```

in this if statement

```
if (numbers[i] % j == 0 || numbers[i] < 2)
```

can never evaluate to true.

At least you should write

```
int lastPrimeNumber = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numbersCount; i++)
{
    bool isPrime = not ( numbers[i] < 2 );

    for (int j = 2; isPrime && j <= numbers[i]/2; j++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] % j == 0)
        {
            isPrime = false;
        }
    }
    if(isPrime)
    {
        lastPrimeNumber = numbers[i];
    }
}
```

A better approach is the following.

```
int lastPrimeNumber = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numbersCount; i++)
{
    bool isPrime = numbers[i] % 2 == 0 ? numbers[i] == 2 : numbers[i] != 1;

    for ( int j = 3; isPrime && j <= numbers[i] / j; j += 2 )
    {
        if (numbers[i] % j == 0)
        {
            isPrime = false;
        }
    }
    if(isPrime)
    {
        lastPrimeNumber = numbers[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix, change

```
bool isPrime = true;
for (int i = 0; i < numbersCount; i++)
{
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbersCount; i++)
{
    bool isPrime = true;
```

In your version once you have set `isPrime` to false you **never** set it back to true again.

Comment: Also, the code counts 1 as prime, part of condition `|| numbers[i] < 2` can never be true

Comment: I did think of that and I tried to do that change, same thing happens. I tried to output the lastPrimeNumber variable in a loop and somehow any numbers are assigned to it and I can't understand why.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen When the number is less than two, the flag is set to false, that means any number lower than 2 isn't prime, or am I missing something?

Comment: @righN Your inner loop (one indexed with `j`) will not run if `numbers[i]` is less than `5`, so the condition in `if` will not be evaluated. This means that actually both `1` and `4` will be classified as prime.

Comment: @righN That's incorrect. If the number is `1` then the loop is never entered, therefore `1` will count as prime.. You should also use `<=` not `<`, at the moment `4` counts a prime.

Comment: @righN Really the prime testing code should be written as a separate function. That makes your code easier to understand but even more importantly allows you to test the prime testing code independently. Since you have several bugs in that part of the code (three so far) that would have been useful.

Comment: @john I'm still learning, just trying something here and there when I have time, still haven't gotten to functions. That's why I don't use them yet, but it seems that I should get to them as soon as possible.